# SQL Find Top Customer with greatest total transaction amount, list transactions, and total all transactions in row at bottom

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollup

Sample data from transactions table..

example

| transaction_id | customer_id | transaction_amount | transaction_location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 600 | 66 | $504.57 | California |
| 601 | 47 | $367.14 | Virginia |
| 602 | 36 | $756.00 | Michigan |
| 603 | 63 | $364.62 | Texas |

**Here is the question:**

List the top 1 customer's transactions who have the highest total transaction amount in such a way that the result shows all the transaction done by the customer and the last row shows the total amount of all the transaction done by the customer.
For Example: The output should be in the following format:

| transaction_id | Transaction_Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50.06 |
| 5 | 298.45 |
| 20 | 400.73 |
| 31 | 75.48 |
| 50 | 1300.15 |
| -------------------------- | ------------------- |
| Total_Transactions_Amount | 2124.87 |

I am working through this. I am thinking perhaps a self join is needed?

```
/*SELECT t1.transaction_amount, t1.transaction_id
FROM Transactions t1
INNER JOIN Transactions t2
ON t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id
...? */
```

I know that I will need to use some sort of rank function or row number function??, or something like that. Really need help in that part.

All in all, I know my code needs to partition over the customer id, and will need some way to rank and output the top #1 customer.

I also know I need a ROLLUP function to tally the total on the row below, but I haven't come to that part of my solution yet.
This is what I have so far.

I figured out that customer #50 is the #1 customer, so for now I was able to partition over the customer id and output all transactions
and Total_Transactions_Amount.

```
SELECT customer_id, transaction_id, transaction_amount, 
 SUM(transaction_amount) 
    OVER (Partition BY customer_id) AS Total_Transactions_Amount 
 FROM Transactions
 WHERE customer_id = 50
 GROUP BY customer_id, transaction_id, transaction_amount
 ORDER BY transaction_amount DESC, customer_id, transaction_id
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn’t a site where someone will do your homework for you. You need to show what you’ve managed to write on your own and then ask a specific question about an issue you are facing. You also need to provide, as editable text, the definitions of the tables, sample data for those tables and the result you want to achieve based on that data

Comment: Wow. Didn't want someone to do my homework for me. I have more info that I'd be happy to share. Hoped someone could point me in the right direction. No need to be snarky...everyone doesn't have bad intentions. I will update with relevant data soon.

Comment: Post updated. NickW, Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi - the solution is likely to be dependant on the specific DBMS you are using, so please can you tag your question with your DBMS (MySQL, Postgresql, SQL Server, etc.)?

Comment: Yes MicroSoft SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Your last query doesn't make much sense really.

First you need to find the customer with the highest total amount:

```
select customer_Id, sum(transaction_amount)
from Transactions
group by customer_id
order by sum(transaction_amount) desc;
```

We only need the top(1), thus:

```
select top(1) customer_Id, sum(transaction_amount)
from Transactions
group by customer_id
order by sum(transaction_amount) desc;
```

And also we really don't need the sum() here, just the customer_id, thus:

```
select top(1) customer_Id
from Transactions
group by customer_id
order by sum(transaction_amount) desc;
```

So far so good, if we knew the customer_id, we would write:

```
SELECT transaction_id, sum(transaction_amount) as transaction_amount 
 FROM Transactions
 WHERE customer_id = 50
 GROUP BY transaction_id
 ORDER BY transaction_id
 with rollup;
```

We actually found that customer_id in the former query so connecting them:

```
SELECT transaction_id,
       SUM(transaction_amount) AS transaction_amount
FROM Transactions
WHERE customer_id IN
      (
          SELECT TOP (1)
                 customer_Id
          FROM Transactions
          GROUP BY customer_id
          ORDER BY SUM(transaction_amount) DESC
      )
GROUP BY transaction_id
ORDER BY transaction_id
with rollup;
```

BTW, used IN () because there might be multiple customers with the same total transaction_amount and you might want to use with ties in that case.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this. This was the last question of my assessment and the only one that stumped me. I already handed it in but I really want to get better. Solving this helps tremendously.

Comment: Even though multiple customer with same total top 1 would pick only one right. whether using `IN` or `=` will output right ?

Comment: @Roshan, it depends. If you require to have them all, then you could add "with ties" and all matching to same max amount would be returned instead of the top 1. I added "you might want to use with ties", for that reason. It is ready for "with ties" IOW.